# change of column length in the underlined table is not getting reflected in the mview

Tags: sql, oracle

Few initial queries

```
create table tab1
(
     fname varchar2(15),
     lname varchar2(15)
);

create materialized view log on tab1 with rowid;

create materialized view mv1 
refresh fast with rowid on commit
as
select * from tab1;
```

Now I have increased the size of fname from `varchar2(15)` to `varchar2(20);`

```
alter table tab1 modify fname varchar2(20);
```

Now this change in the column size is not getting reflected in the mview.

By querying `desc mlog$_tab1;`

I came  to know it actually keeps track of only information based on `rowid.`

So how I can the column size of mview be changed?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't experienced this in Oracle, only in MSSQL. What I had to do was "refresh" the view by running an ALTER VIEW with the same contents it already had, and that made the trick. Perhaps that's not a good option for you, but I just wanted to share my 2 cents.

Comment: Drop and recreate the MV.

Comment: Andrew and Nitish are right, but I'd try it with `ALTER` before a `DROP` and `CREATE`.  `ALTER` will better preserve any associated entities (security, indexes, etc.) that might not survive `DROP`, and if you're working on a view that is queried by other views, stored procedures, or functions then `DROP` is non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can either drop/recreate, or simply alter the snapshot table of the mat view to reflect the change made in the underlying table:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> set lines 500
SQL> drop table test_mv_tab
Table dropped.
SQL> create table test_mv_tab
(
  my_col varchar2(10)
)
Table created.
SQL> insert into test_mv_tab values ('ABC')
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> drop MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST_MV
Materialized View dropped.
SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST_MV
NOCACHE
NOLOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOPARALLEL
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
AS
select * from test_mv_tab
Materialized View created.
SQL> -- show column
SQL> select column_name, data_length from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'TEST_MV'

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_LENGTH
------------------------------ -----------
MY_COL                                  10
1 row selected.
SQL> -- change underyling table
SQL> ALTER TABLE TEST_MV_TAB
MODIFY(MY_COL VARCHAR2(15 BYTE))
Table altered.
SQL> -- refresh mat view complete
SQL> exec dbms_mview.refresh('TEST_MV','C',atomic_refresh=>false)
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SQL> -- show column
SQL> select column_name, data_length from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'TEST_MV'

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_LENGTH
------------------------------ -----------
MY_COL                                  10
1 row selected.
SQL> -- alter snapshot table of view
SQL> ALTER TABLE TEST_MV
MODIFY(MY_COL VARCHAR2(15 BYTE))
Table altered.
SQL> -- refresh mat view complete
SQL> exec dbms_mview.refresh('TEST_MV','C',atomic_refresh=>false)
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SQL> -- show column
SQL> select column_name, data_length from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'TEST_MV'

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_LENGTH
------------------------------ -----------
MY_COL                                  15
1 row selected.
```